# What is the use of cvGetRows() function in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

When should i use this function. Can anybody explain me with an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Documentation,](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=getrows#getrow-s) it`Returns array row or row span.` It returns the rows you specified.

I will explain it with the help of Python terminal:

Load image in grayscale mode and check its width and height.

```
>>> import cv2.cv as cv
>>> img = cv.LoadImage('approx2.jpg',0)
>>> img
<iplimage(nChannels=1 width=300 height=300 widthStep=300 )>
```

See, image is 300x300 size. Below is the image.

[image]

Taking sum all pixels,

```
>>> cv.Sum(img)
(1252271.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Now we apply our first function, cv.GetRow()

```
>>> row = cv.GetRow(img,150)
>>> row
<cvmat(type=42424000 8UC1 rows=1 cols=300 step=300 )>

>>> cv.Sum(row)
(14279.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

I took the 150th row and took sum of all elements in that row. See resulting image has height = 1.

Now taking function cv.GetRows().

```
>>> rows = cv.GetRows(img,0,150)
>>> rows
<cvmat(type=42424000 8UC1 rows=150 cols=300 step=300 )>

>>> cv.Sum(rows)
(802501.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

I took all the rows from upto 150th. See its height is 150. Check out image below:

[image]

Now there is a fourth argument on this function `delta_row` which can be used as increment. It will select the rows which is an increment of the step size mentioned, skipping everything in between. ie if specified, `the function extracts every delta_row -th row from start_row and up to (but not including) end_row .`

```
>>> rows = cv.GetRows(img,0,300,5)
>>> rows
<cvmat(type=42420000 8UC1 rows=60 cols=300 step=1500 )>
```

See, now height is only 30 because it extracts every 5th row.

Result is below :

[image]

Similar is the case with `cv.GetCol() and cv.GetCols()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found another invocation of method.Let consider this C++ code segment.

```
CvMat* input_matrix,sub_matrix;
int start,end;
//declarations of variables go here
cvGetRows(input_matrix, &sub_matrix, start, end);
```

Function takes the rows from start_row to end_row in input_matrix and point it by sub_matrix pointer. Now we can fill values of start row to end row in input_matrix using that pointer.